# Bash : Reload home directory (/etc/passwd) without logging out

Tags: debian, bash

I'm on a Debian Wheezy, and I'm wondering how I can, after editing /etc/passwd (actually to change a home directory, but nevermind), reload the user session without logging off.

I tried `exec bash`, `exec bash --login`, but it doesn't work

Any idea ?

NB : whatever I change on /etc/passwd I would like a command to refresh the user's session

EDIT : This may be a question for StackOverFlow. If so, please moove my question, thx.

Comment: what about `su - "your Usernam"`

Comment: wow, that simple... It works. Please write it on an answer, so I can validate it. I was however expecting a command without having to type a password, but it's ok.

Comment: Sudoers entry with NOPASSWD?

Comment: well, I don't have sudo, just a root account and many classic user with no right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use `su - "your username"`

as a hack, if you like to do this without entering a password you could add the following line to /etc/sudoers

> `"your username" ALL=("your username") su`

and then use the following command
`sudo su - "your username"`